# How to check whether installed Excel is Licensed or not?

Tags: c#, excel, interop, office-interop

I am Creating an application which is responsible to read or right Excel files. Below code give me whether Excel is installed or not. Is there any Provision to check the installed excel is Registered/Licensed?

```
Type officeType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
if (officeType == null)
{
     //no Excel installed
}
else
{
     //Excel installed
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.   Why does the application need to know?

Comment: Also, you can't rely too much on COM registration (your `Type.GetTypeFromProgID` code) because its entirely possible the Windows Registry has orphaned entries pointing to non-existant software

Answer (score 0):

You could check if there is a key in the registry

There is a Script that can do so for Office for example

Open an administrative level command prompt.
Navigate to the Office14 folder:

```
32bit Office on 64bit OS – “cd \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14”
32bit Office on 32bit OS and 64bit Office on 64bit OS – “cd \Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14”
```

Execute “cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus”

The script searches somewhere around here for my Office version

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\ClickToRun\Configuration\SharedComputerLicensing
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration\SharedComputerLicensing
```